# Unable to present my accepted paper in conference. Can I now submit the paper to another conference?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

My one technical paper was recently accepted for one international conference. 
But, unfortunately, I am not able to attend as the Conference dates are conflicting with my official assignments. I intimated the Conference about my inability to attend. On my request, the conference acknowledged that they will not publish my paper to their Journals/proceedings. (I have the full set of email communications with the conference secretariat.)

I wish to submit the same paper for an IEEE conference. Is there any issue? Please advise.

Comment: Huh? Why didn't you check the dates of the conference when you submitted?

Comment: And why wouldn't you ask a co-author or a colleague to present in your place?

Answer (score 0):

> On my request, the conference acknowledged that they will not publish
>   my paper to their Journals/proceedings. (I've the email transactions
>   with the conference secretariat.)

Was the registration for the paper done, i.e. you had paid the registration fee? Was the camera ready version already submitted?

If you had not paid the fee already, then obviously they won't publish your work. In fact, they won't consider for scheduling the program as well. If you had already paid the fee and submitted the CR version, be safe and keep the email transactions with you for possible conflicts in future. However, AFAIK, many conferences don't publish the work unless the registered author presents the paper in the conference. Make sure this is the policy for this conference as well.

> I wish to submit the same paper for an IEEE conference. Is there any
>   issue? Please advise.

If you think you are safe in the first question (above), then you could go ahead with submitting to another conference.

You can further view the following related questions in academia SE:

- [Would my paper be published if I missed the conference due to visa-related problems?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80313/would-my-paper-be-published-if-i-missed-the-conference-due-to-visa-related-probl?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What to do if I can't get a visa to attend a conference that accepted my paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/what-to-do-if-i-cant-get-a-visa-to-attend-a-conference-that-accepted-my-paper?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Etiquette when unable to attend a conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/etiquette-when-unable-to-attend-a-conference)

*BTW, I had a question, why did you submit the paper to the already-accepted conference at the first place if you were not sure about your attendance? I feel this is not a good sign.*

Comment: _If you had not paid the fee already, then obviously they won't publish your work._ — Not so "obviously"! In practice, this **strongly** depends on the conference.  For major conferences in theoretical CS, authors are _expected_ to register, but nobody actually checks; camera-ready papers and copyright forms are due long before the registration deadlines.  As long as _somebody_ presents the paper, the conference organizes are happy.  (I've presented several conference papers for authors whose visa/health issues prevented then from attending.)

Comment: The online registration was done, but the registration charges not yet paid. The camera ready version not yet submitted. As I had mentioned some official assignment came conflicting with the dates..